# How to pass multiple parameters in UILongPressGestureRecognizer iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, target

I want to pass some parameters with UILongPressGestureRecognizer method in iOS Swift 4.* .

```
let buttonLongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressedLong(_:)))
button.addGestureRecognizer(buttonLongGesture)

@objc func buttonPressedLong(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Comment: @LalKrishna Check it now.

Comment: Passing parameters in this way is weird and confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you make a custom class inherit UI LongPressGestureRecognizer then you can add any parameters as variables there. Finally you can use it to send parameters when the gesture happens. Here's an example.

```
class CustomLongPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
    var firstParam: String!
    var secondParam: String!
}
```

Then you can implement it like this:

```
func setUp() {
    let buttonLongGesture = CustomLongPressGesture(target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressedLong(_:)))
    buttonLongGesture.firstParam = "Test"
    buttonLongGesture.secondParam = "Second Test"
    button.addGestureRecognizer(buttonLongGesture)
}

 @objc func buttonPressedLong(_ sender: CustomLongPressGesture) {
    print(sender.firstParam, sender.secondParam) // Access it here
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.It's interesting answer.

Comment: It's my pleasure :D @reza_khalafi